# How do I undo nhibernate mappings

Tags: nhibernate

I have an nHibernate project where all the tables have been mapped.  I'd like to eliminate most of the mappings - and use pass through sql for the eliminated tables. For the remaining mappings, I'd like to continue using nHibernate. 
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What about just removing the mapping declarations, e.g. XML files?

Comment: "Eliminate the mappings" sounds like the wrong conclusion for a symptom you have. Besides that it would be easy to just delete the mapping files or exclude them from building.

Comment: Considering what @Firo wrote: Please note that you also can use NHibernate and SQL together, see the [documentation on queries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql) and [DML statements](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct). Perhaps you can tell us more about your problem(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance I would leave them mapped to *guarantee* (as much as possible) that no existing code breaks.

I would then profile the application to see where bottle necks lay using a tool like [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof). This will give you an insight to where your performance bottle necks lie.

You can then override your existing code to get closer to the metal using raw SQL. However I would still recommend that you look at a micro orm such as [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) that can still execute a SQL query and map the results to a strongly typed List.

If your problem lies in inserts then a) use a stateless session or use a another tool like [SQL Bulk copy](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/).

If you do this right you may not need to change any of your model classes which means that you are likely to break less code. However been warned that eager/lazy loading issues might start to crop up.